# How do I control a table of SVG images in html?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, svg, html-table

I want to make a table of SVG images. The code below works fine in firefox, making two adjacent black squares which scale up to the size of the table cells, but in Chrome the svg images are small things inside the table cells.

Am I doing something silly? Is there a portable way to get the SVGs to scale to fit the table properly?

```
<table width="800" height="400" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
 <td>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 220 220"><rect width="220" height="220"/>
  </svg>
 </td>
 <td>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 220 220"><rect width="220" height="220"/>
  </svg>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only somewhat portable way seems to be to use absolute values for the svg width/height, as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rd7ed/1/.

```
svg { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

But, in Chrome the above seems to cause the border to not be drawn completely around the table (a bug probably).

Using percentage width and height instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Rd7ed/ (this is not working correctly in Chrome, which is probably another bug).

Perhaps you could use one svg instead and no table at all?